# How to use th:block and th:include in thymeleaf?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

[image: Visual]

My html other pages is in the edit folder.

I am currently using this script below

```
<!--/*/ <th:block th:include="fragments/header :: header"></th:block> /*/-->
```

Script above works if the html document is in the same directory. (Eg; index.html is able to read the fragments). But I created a new directory(named: edit) to store my html pages. I need to get out of the current folder so it would be able to find the fragment folder using ../

```
<!--/*/ <th:block th:include="../fragments/header :: header"></th:block> /*/-->
```

But this method does not work. How would I be able to exit out a folder using this syntax?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you are using Spring Boot. Spring Boot autoconfigures Thymeleaf to find all HTML files in `/templates`.

In the [default application.properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties) you can see it:

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
```

So (because Thymeleaf uses `/templates` as root) that should work:

```
<th:block th:include="fragments/header :: header"></th:block>
```

And/or:

```
<th:block th:include="/fragments/header :: header"></th:block>
```

You don't "need to get out of the current folder".

Comment: I found an interesting phenomenon, when i start the path without / in local dev,it's ok,but after i package the project to jar file,thymeleaf can not find the fragment.i do not find more details for  this.

Comment: @janwen Maybe you can make a new issue for the Spring developers?

Answer (score -3):

I've not used Thymeleaf before, but this [forum post](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/Relative-th-include-paths-td4028161.html) may be of some use to you.

It seems to indicate that there's a way to set up the paths to use a **prefix** and **suffix** mechanism, to avoid the need to provide a path itself at this stage.

Comment: This should have been a comment